# Outlook message preview bug when sending from Outlook

Tags: email, outlook, html-email

I know most of you are lucky not to deal with this, but unfortunately I have to, so...

I have a client who is sending emails from Outlook, and I've been creating some .oft templates for her. All is good, she is fine that email is not responsive and most of these are internal emails that got opened in Outlook anyway.

But, whenever I have an image header as a first thing in the email, the Outlook preview pane is displaying IMAGE URL as a first line in message preview instead of image alt tag or anything else for that matter.

Not sure if there's a fix for this? Any help is appreciated.

Tried adding the alt tag to the header image, changing it in Outlook before sending - nothing helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outlook 2013-2019 will preview the first 35 characters of an email. You have two  choices, you could instruct your client to always start with text and treat it like a secondary subject line or you can add a hidden area with 35 `&nbsp;` in a row so that the client can start with an image, but then you lose out on preview text.

```
<div style="font-size: 1px; line-height:1px; display: none !important; mso-hide:all;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
```

Or...

```
<div style="font-size: 1px; line-height:1px; display: none !important; mso-hide:all;">Dealing with Outlook's shortcomings</div>
```

The easiest might be to convince them to make it a second subject line for every message so they get into the habit of using this so that the url issue never shows up again.

More information on preview text:

- https://litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-preview-text-support

Good luck.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks a lot.The first way (35 &nbsp;) did not work for me, the preview text was still displaying the image URL.  But adding the hidden div before the image with the preview text (non-empty) of my choosing worked great.

Comment: And, my Outlook (Microsoft Outlook for Office 365 MSO) default view is 3 lines of text as a preview - so it seems that &nbsp; option would work as well but you will need lot more than 35 of them! Thanks!

Comment: You didn't specify which version of Outlook you are supporting, so I covered the last few desktop versions and what they support. If you looked at the link I shared, you'd see how many characters various email clients will preview. The good news is now you have a solution.

Comment: @gwally "By default it shows 35" but the user has an option to show more. See image --> https://i.stack.imgur.com/gND3O.png. So its best to add more just in case ;-)